# Store templated class in persistent memory?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I want to write information from a template class to a file, and then be able to read from a file to create an instance of that template class. I know how I can write it (use a `std::ofstream`, write its template parameters and relevant information), but I'm kind of lost on reading it back. I could read the template parameters from the file, but it can't compile that instance of the template class at runtime, so it would fail (or wouldn't compile at all). The reason I want to do this is so I can store something in persistent memory. The class I'm trying to do this for is Eigen's Tensor class, if that helps at all (the example given is more general, and a solution to it would still work). Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

An example:

```
template<int example> class A{
    //omitted constructors and everything else
    void write(std::ofstream& out){ //writes relevant information of class to a file
        out<<example;
    }
};
```

As for reading the file:

```
void read(std::ifstream& in){
    int example;
    in>>example;
    A<example> a; //doesn't work because A<example> can't be compiled at runtime
}
```

**EDIT:**
I understand how template classes work, and that they're only compiled if they are used. I also understand why my example doesn't work. My question is if it is possible for me to compile new instances at runtime. I know it is possible to do this with .cpp files (not sure how, I just know it is possible). I don't know if it is possible with template classes, however. My current solution will probably be to make my program create new executables and run those, so they will have the necessary things already compiled, but that is slow and unsatisfactory, so I'm leaving this question up in hopes of getting a better solution.

Comment: ‘Compile new instances at runtime’ - surely not, unless you program a compiler. Consider that the compiler might reside on a different machine than your executable is running. How could the executable trigger and execute a compilation without having a complete compiler included?

Comment: @Aganju I really only care about getting it to run on my machine, as I'm only writing this program to learn about something completely unrelated to this issue. I could easily switch to python and use tensorflow or numpy, but I have a few reasons I don't want to.

Answer (score -1):

Template arguments must be known at compile-time anyway. So you may not pass some variable value as a template argument.

Comment: I realize that, the reason I asked the question was to see if there was some way around that.

Comment: Does using 'int' as a constructor parameter meets your requirement? Just like the constructor of std::vector does.

Comment: No, I didn't write the class I'm trying to do this for, and it's far too complicated and has too many dependencies for me to attempt to change it.

Answer (score -1):

Template classes are what the name says - *templates* for building the real thing once a parameter is given. There is no object of a template class, and you can obviously not write a non-existent thing in a file or read it.
Without instantiating your template with a parameter, nothing gets compiled - the template class is just the instruction for the compiler how to build it *if needed*.